# Two calls access a static variable with different results

Tags: java, rmi, remote-access

I'm getting this issue while trying to access a shared static variable between two different methods...

Suppose that the environment should be like this:

Method 1 with RMI interface CommonUtils:

```
CommonUtils service = registry.lookup("chat"); //i'm sure that it works fine
service.register(String username);...
```

Implementation of CommonUtils:

```
public static ArrayList<ChatInterface> connectedChat=new ArrayList<ChatInterface>();
public static void register(String username){
     connectedChat.add(username);
}
public static String getChatByUsername(String username){
    for(ConnetctedChat temp:connectedChat)
       if (temp.getUsername().equals(username))
           return temp;
} ...
```

Method 2 calls the utils directly from the same library:

```
String username;
ChatInterface tmp=CommonUtils.getChatByUsername(username); <---- This is "the problem"
```

Now, when I try to inspect what is inside the "ArrayList connectedChat", I see two different results: the right one is when I take info from the first method. Otherwise, when I try to take something out from the "Method 2", it says that the ArrayList is empty, so I can't operate anymore (but from the other method it seems that the list isn't empty!).

The thing that I'm trying to resolve is a kind of Chat service... it works from client sender - server - client receiver, but it seems that it doesn't work in the simply server sender - client receiver communication.

Comment: are multiple threads making calls into your CommonUtils class?  if so, you have concurrency issues (simple solution is to make all the methods in CommonUtils which interact with the shared data synchronized).

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, but are the two calls made in the same JVM process or are these two different JVM processes?

Comment: Also, the question is not very clear. The method declares a String as return type, but your call is `ChatInterface tmp=CommonUtils.getChatByUsername(username);`. And you're not trying to call a static method remotely, are you? Because that can't work.

Comment: @JBNizet typing error, it returns a ChatInterface

Comment: @Vikdor the process are two different process (a Client and a "Server" one), i suppose that they use the same variables at runtime, also if they are in 2 distinct projects (they use the library where CommonUtils is located)

Comment: @jtahlborn i'm going to take a look on the synchronized blocks... but i'm not sure that could be a sync problem...

Comment: If you look at a static variable of the class on the client JVM, you won't see the same list as the static variable of the same class on the server JVM. Static fields are associated to the class, and are not magically accessed remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be expecting static variables to be shared between JVMs by RMI. They aren't. That's why remote methods exist.